# Formulate a Linear Program of minimizing maximum distance from a set of points to a line and formulate its dual

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Say we define the distance from a point to a line in the plane as the length of the vertical distance "you would have to walk" from the point till you hit the line.

Then find a line $L:y=ax+b$ , where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ in the plane that minimize the maximum distance from the points $(1,1),(2,2),(2,4),(3,2)$ to $L$.

How would you formulate this problem as a linear problem and write down its dual LP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ask yourself what your variables are: $a$ and $b$.

Next, what are you minimizing? The maximum distance to the line, that is
$$
\max_i\{|y_i-(ax_i+b)|\},
$$
where $(x_i,y_i)$ are your set of points. You are going to need to linearize this expression. Here is a start: you are going to want to minimize 
$$
z
$$
subject to
$$
|y_i-(ax_i+b)| \le z \quad \forall i
$$
Can you do the last bit (get rid of the absolute values)?

Comment: \begin{aligned}
& \underset{\{a,b,d\}}{\text{minimize}}
& & d \\
& \text{ st.}
& & \begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\
-1&-1&-1\\2&1&-1\\-2&-1&-1\\2&1&-1\\-2&1&-1\\3&1&-1\\-3&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\d \end{pmatrix}\leq\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\2\\-2\\4\\-4\\2\\-2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Applying the expression of the distance from points $x_i,y_i$ to line this the LP i get

Comment: And converting to the dual problem I get

Comment: \begin{aligned}
& {\text{max}}
& & u_1-u_2+2u_3-2u_4+4u_5-4u_6+2u_7-2u_8 \\
& \text{ st.}
& & \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2&-2&2&-2&3&-3\\
1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1\\
-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3\\u_4\\u_5\\u_6\\u_7\\u_8 \end{pmatrix}
\leq\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Is the correct dual? If so how would I go about solving the dual problem? Put it into standard form, start with a basis consisting of the three added slack variables and solve like I would would the primal using the tableau?

Comment: It looks right! I think the $u$ variables should be negative though.